# How do I get unique values from nested Many-To-Many joins

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

Basically we have four tables that are joined: Malls, Stores, Brands, and Categories.

Malls can have many Stores.
Each Store is linked to a Brand.
Each Brand has many Categories.

e.g. Mall A has 2 "McDonald's Cafes", each belonging to the Brand "McDonald's". "McDonald's" Brand has "Fast Food" and "Breakfast" as Categories.

We're trying to figure out how to display all the Categories that exist within Mall A.

e.g. Mall A has "Fast Food" and "Breakfast" categories, based on the "McDonald's" stores.

Ideally this would be a query so that the Categories are updated automatically.

We've tried querying for all Stores within a Mall, and then finding the Categories via the Store-Brand join, then reducing duplicates. But some Malls have more than 700 Stores, so this process is quite expensive in terms of querying and processing the data.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out! Using Sequelize, my query was as follows:

```
postgres.BrandsCategories.findAndCountAll({
      limit,
      offset,
      include: [
        {
          model: postgres.Brands,
          as: "brands",
          include: [
            {
              model: postgres.Stores,
              as: "stores",
              where: {
                mallId: parent.dataValues.id
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    })
```